# is it possible to 'clone' all repositories on a running GraphDB instance to a new server?

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

tldr: can I just copy the parent directory with all my repositories to the new machine?

I have a GraphDB (free) server with 8 repositories that I need to move to new hardware.  Is there documentation on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can stop GraphDB and copy it's data folder to a new instance. More information can be found at the documentation - https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/backing-up-and-recovering-repo.html#back-up-graphdb-by-copying-the-binary-image